# C# Java HashMap equivalent

Tags: c#, java, hashmap

Coming from a Java world into a C# one is there a HashMap equivalent? If not what would you recommend?

Answer (score 662, accepted):

[`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) is probably the closest. `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` implements the [`System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2) interface (which is similar to Java's `Map` interface).

Some notable differences that you should be aware of:

- Adding/Getting items

  - Java's HashMap has the `put` and `get` methods for setting/getting items

    - `myMap.put(key, value)`
    - `MyObject value = myMap.get(key)`
  - C#'s Dictionary uses `[]` indexing for setting/getting items

    - `myDictionary[key] = value`
    - `MyObject value = myDictionary[key]`
- `null` keys

  - Java's `HashMap` allows null keys
  - .NET's `Dictionary` throws an `ArgumentNullException` if you try to add a null key
- Adding a duplicate key

  - Java's `HashMap` will replace the existing value with the new one.
  - .NET's `Dictionary` will replace the existing value with the new one if you use `[]` indexing.  If you use the `Add` method, it will instead throw an `ArgumentException`.
- Attempting to get a non-existent key

  - Java's `HashMap` will return null.
  - .NET's `Dictionary` will throw a `KeyNotFoundException`.  You can use the [`TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue) method instead of the `[]` indexing to avoid this:
    `MyObject value = null;
    if (!myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value)) { /* key doesn't exist */ }`

`Dictionary`'s has a [`ContainsKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey) method that can help deal with the previous two problems.

Comment: There isn't an exact equivalent (in JAVA HashMap permits null values and the null key) http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Yes, Dictionary is close but not exact.

Comment: Note, `Dictionary` throws Exceptions when adding a duplicated key.

Comment: Also, an Exception is thrown when requesting a value with a non existing key.

Comment: `if (!myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, value))` needs an `out` for the second argument. So `if (!myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))`

Comment: @bugybunny Good catch.  This is why you should always test code when putting it into answers... and I clearly didn't.

Comment: Note that if `TryGetValue` returns false, it **also** sets `value` to `default` for its type (typically 0 or null, which would be similar to what `HashMap` returns). So if you're happy with that, in some case you don't even need to check the boolean result of `TryGetValue`

Answer (score 40):

From [C# equivalent to Java HashMap](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/614128f7-d1d2-45df-9ae1-c53a0c74ddbf/)

I needed a Dictionary which accepted a "null" key, but there seems to be no native one, so I have written my own. It's very simple, actually. I inherited from Dictionary, added a private field to hold the value for the "null" key, then overwritten the indexer. It goes like this :

```
public class NullableDictionnary : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    string null_value;

    public StringDictionary this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (key == null) 
            {
                return null_value;
            }
            return base[key];
        }
        set
        {
            if (key == null)
            {
                null_value = value;
            }
            else 
            {
                base[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.

==========

I modified it to this format

```
public class NullableDictionnary : Dictionary<string, object>
```

Comment: Couldn't you continue the generics theme by making object a type parameter?

Comment: This doesn't work. 
public StringDictionary this[string key] {...
should be
public String this[string key] {. Also base[key] won't work from my try. I suggest implementing IDictionary and just having a global private dictionary object and handling the null case for each of the methods.

Comment: I wonder why you went out of your way to misspell Dictionary.

Comment: @JimBalter Clearly he needs a dictionary.

Answer (score 33):

Let me help you understand it with an example of "codaddict's algorithm"

'***Dictionary*** in C#' is '***Hashmap*** in Java' in parallel universe.

Some implementations are different. See the example below to understand better.

Declaring Java HashMap:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> pairs = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Declaring C# Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, int> Pairs = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

Getting a value from a location:

```
pairs.get(input[i]); // in Java
Pairs[input[i]];     // in C#
```

Setting a value at location:

```
pairs.put(k - input[i], input[i]); // in Java
Pairs[k - input[i]] = input[i];    // in C#
```

An Overall Example can be observed from below Codaddict's algorithm.

**codaddict's algorithm in Java:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ArrayPairSum {

    public static void printSumPairs(int[] input, int k)
    {
        Map<Integer, Integer> pairs = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        {
            if (pairs.containsKey(input[i]))
                System.out.println(input[i] + ", " + pairs.get(input[i]));
            else
                pairs.put(k - input[i], input[i]);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = { 2, 45, 7, 3, 5, 1, 8, 9 };
        printSumPairs(a, 10);

    }
}
```

**Codaddict's algorithm in C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void checkPairs(int[] input, int k)
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> Pairs = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Pairs.ContainsKey(input[i]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(input[i] + ", " + Pairs[input[i]]);
            }
            else
            {
                Pairs[k - input[i]] = input[i];
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = { 2, 45, 7, 3, 5, 1, 8, 9 };
        //method : codaddict's algorithm : O(n)
        checkPairs(a, 10);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: C#9.0 comment: you can use `new()` if you know the type of a variable, instead of typing out `new Dictionary<int, int>()` for example. :) (this answer was posted way before C#9.0 but readers using this code are advised to write more readable code)

Answer (score 8):

Use Dictionary - it uses hashtable but is typesafe.

Also, your Java code for

```
int a = map.get(key);
//continue with your logic
```

will be best coded in C# this way:

```
int a;
if(dict.TryGetValue(key, out a)){
//continue with your logic
}
```

This way, you can scope the need of variable "a" inside a block and it is still accessible outside the block if you need it later.

Comment: `dict.TryGetValue(key, out int a)` since  C# 7.0.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the documentation on MSDN for the [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable%28VS.71%29.aspx) class.

> Represents a collection of key-and-value pairs that are organized based on the hash code of the key.

Also, keep in mind that this is not thread-safe.

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is preferable, because of compile time type checking and because it doesn't require boxing of value types.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is

> Dictionary

take look at my function, its simple add uses most important member functions inside Dictionary

this function return false if the list contain Duplicates items

```
 public static bool HasDuplicates<T>(IList<T> items)
    {
        Dictionary<T, bool> mp = new Dictionary<T, bool>();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (mp.ContainsKey(items[i]))
            {
                return true; // has duplicates
            }
            mp.Add(items[i], true);
        }
        return false; // no duplicates
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to give my two cents.
This is according to @Powerlord 's answer.

Puts **"null"** instead of **null** strings.

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public static void put(string key, string value)
{
    if (value == null) value = "null";
    map[key] = value;
}

public static string get(string key, string defaultValue)
{
    try
    {
        return map[key];
    }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException e)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

public static string get(string key)
{
    return get(key, "null");
}
```