# Create a List of int & DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, list

I want to create a List like this :

```
List<int, DateTime> foo = new List<int, DateTime>();
```

but I get this error :

`Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

Is it possible to do that in C# ?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  You need a class.

Comment: A `List<T>` can be only of _one_ type. Do you want to create a [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)?

Comment: It is possible in java using HashMap

Comment: Not a dictionnary, I want to give for every DateTime an ID.

Comment: @OpenMind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273139/c-sharp-java-hashmap-equivalent

Comment: @nycdan I don't want to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.

You can for example use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) if you want to use int as an index to access a DateTime like this:

```
Dictionary<int, DateTime> dict = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();

dict.Add(1, DateTime.Now);
DateTime d = dict[1];
```

Or if you want to store an arbitrary list of values and allow duplicates you can use:

```
  var values = new List<Tuple<int, DateTime>>();
  values.Add(new Tuple<int, DateTime>(1, DateTime.Now));
  Tuple<int, DateTime> value = values.First();
```

Answer (score 9):

You can have a list of int/DateTime [Tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).

```
var foo = new List<Tuple<int, DateTime>>();
```

This does require .Net 4.0+.

I personally prefer creating a simple class and using that for my list.  I think it's more readable than nesting generics.

```
// I don't know your domain so the example is with names I'd hate to actually see
class MyType
{
    public int MyInteger {get; set;}
    public DateTime MyDateTime {get; set;}
}
```

One could also use `dynamic` and send it an anonymous type.

```
var foo = new List<dynamic>();

foo.Add(new {X = 0, D = DateTime.Now});

foreach(var d in foo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `List<Tuple<int,DateTime>>` if you are using .NET 4.0 or above.

An alternative is to create a simple class that will serve as a generic type - the benefit of that is that of readability (giving descriptive names to the type and properties).

```
List<MyType> myList = new List<MyType>();

class MyType
{
   public int TheInt { get; set; }
   public DateTime TheDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `List<T>` type only takes a single generic type argument but you are providing two.  If you want to store two values in each slot you need to use a wrapper type which can contain the two values.  For example

```
class Storage {
  public int IntValue { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateValue { get; set; }
}

List<Storage> list = ...;
```

If you would like to avoid creating a custom type you can also use `Tuple<int, DateTime>`

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using a [`Tuple<int, DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) or [`KeyValuePair<int, DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx), collected within a `List<T>`. You get the error because the `List<T>` contains one generic parameter as it stores a single collection of elements (which are all of one base type).

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a class that encapsulate the two properties ?

```
public class Foo
{
 public int ID { set;get;}
 public DateTime CreatedDate { set;get;}

}
```

Then you can create a List of that class

```
 List<Foo> objFooList=new List<Foo>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `List<T>` with one generic type parameter, not `List<T, K>`.  Maybe you want to use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead?

Answer (score 0):

List can only contain one type. You can do two things here:

1. Create a list of tuple

   `List<Tuple<int,DateTime>>`
2. Use dictionary

   `Dictionary<int, DateTime>`