# ArrayList and HashMap using directives

Tags: string, arraylist, hashmap, xamarin

In Xamarin, what using directives do I need to use for the following line of code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<string, string>> productList;
```

I cannot resolve the ArrayList or the HashMap.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Java HashMap equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273139/c-sharp-java-hashmap-equivalent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These classes are located in java.util namespace, but remember that *Java generics do not exist*. So, there are no generics versions (seems they existed in the past).

Try to convert `ArrayList` to `List` and `HashMap` to `Dictionary`.