# How to create a HashMap in C#

Tags: java, c#, dictionary, hashmap

I know we can create a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) in Java. But I want to create a HashMap in C# for my ASP.NET MVC project.

Is this possible to do? If yes, how?

In Java we can create a HashMap like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
//...
HashMap<Name, Value> myDictionary = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Why did youtag this as a Java question?

Comment: `Dictionary<Key,Value>` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273139/c-sharp-java-hashmap-equivalent

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273139/c-sharp-java-hashmap-equivalent

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at `Dictionary<key,value>` in the `System.Collections.Generic`. It is the C# "parallel" (albeit having some differences, it is the closest to) of `HashMap` in Java.

Comment: that means I have to go for dictionary

Comment: @Ian, could you explain the differences?

Comment: @cskwrd here they are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273139/c-sharp-java-hashmap-equivalent

Answer (score 2):

```
var myHashMap = new Dictionary<string,object>();
```

Change the types `string` and `object` to whatever you need.