# What data-structure should I use to represent many-to-one mapping?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a set of objects that can be accessed with multiple keys, what structure should I use to represent this in memory?  The only operation I require is a finder that will return me the value giving a key.

For example:

```
key: {"a","aa","aaa"}, value {1}
key: {"b","bb","bbb"}, value {2}
key: {"c","cc","ccc"}, value {3}
```

I would use it like this:

```
MyStruct.Get["a"]; // return 1
MyStruct.Get["aa"]; // return 1
MyStruct.Get["bbb"]; // return 2
MyStruct.Get["d"]; // return null
```

Comment: To my knowledge, this doesn't exist in the class library.  You can easily create your own structure.  Does the order of the keys matter?  Keep that in mind...

Comment: Order of keys does not matter, there is no pre-built structure?  In Java there is HashMap.

Comment: I think you meant `"aaa"` in the first key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Java HashMap equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273139/c-sharp-java-hashmap-equivalent)

Comment: If keys 'a' and 'aa' both evaluate to the same value (e.g. 1), and then you change ['a'] to another value (e.g. 0), should ['aa'] then also evaluate to the updated value (0 in this example)?

Comment: If the only operation you require is a finder, how do you insert data into this structure? Not trying to be pedantic, I think it genuinely influences the answer.

Comment: @DanForbes Yes, a Adder is required, I mean that's definitely nessessary.

Comment: @FirstStep Yes, you are right, it should be "aaa"

Comment: So what does that interface look like? Is each key mapping to the same value added separately, or do you add them all at once, like w/ an array?

Comment: @DanForbes Well I don't think it matters, it would be nice if I could add them all at once like an array, but I can easily foreach the value seperately.

Comment: So then why not just use a `Dictionary`?

Comment: I wasn't sure if Dictionary would duplicate value when added, but it seem like it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).
And you can use it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
myDict.Add("a", 1);
myDict.Add("aa", 1);
myDict.Add("c", 3);

int result;
if (myDict.TryGetValue("a", out result)){
   //do something with result
}
```

Or you can do the lookup like this:

```
int result1 = myDict["a"]; //throws exception when the value is not present
```

Be careful when using your own classes for the TKey parameter. If you do so, you should override the .Equals and .GetHashCode methods.

Comment: Careful, strings are immutable.  "1" <> "1" reference-wise.  You should make that clear.  For longer strings, it could be a problem.

Comment: Also, `Dictionary` throws an exception if you enter duplicated key. Worth mentioning.

Comment: @FirstStep -- not entering a dupe key, just dupe values (if you take into account my first comment, that is).

Comment: @roryap It works absolutely fine for strings. Also, there is no difference in C# between using .Equals and `==` for strings.

Comment: @RicardoPieper -- I'm not saying it doesn't work.  I'm just saying it for memory purposes and efficiency, mainly.

Comment: My problem is does it all link to the same object?  I mean in this example I use int, but in my actual code, I have a class object.  I don't want to have to duplicate the object value.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu --  just pass the same object for all of your keys that reference that object.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu I recommend you override the .Equals and .GetHashCode methods when using your own class for the TKey parameter. Be explicit on how to differentiate 2 objects.

Comment: As for the TValue parameter, it does not matter, as roryap said.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu I have just read again your question. While a `Dictionary<string, int>` *~solves~* the prolem, I started to think whether this is the best way to do so. In your dataset, check if you have more distinct keys than values. If you have only a handful of different values and many different keys, I think you should invert those and use a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` instead.

However, if you absolutely need to do the lookup using the string, then go ahead, this should be good enough.

Comment: I think it might also be worth mentioning that when using your own type for the key that it should be immutable.  Using mutable types for keys is possible but leads to a world of pain if you're not careful.

Comment: @RicardoPieper Thanks a lot for the consideration, unfrotunately I have to have the Many-To-One mapping, so I guess Dictionary is the way to go!