# What is Equivalent of NSMutableDictionary(), NSMutableArray() ,NSArray And NSDictionary in c#?

Tags: xamarin.ios, c#-3.0

Can any one tell me what is equivalent of NSMutableDictionary(), NSMutableArray() ,NSArray  And NSDictionary  in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no difference from `mutable` and `immutable` on `Array` and `Dictionary` in C#.

We can both change the value after it is initialized. It means they are all `Mutable`.

#### For `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSDictionary`

```
  Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  dict["a"] = new NSString(); // set
  var Object = dict["a"];  //get
```

#### For `NSMutableArray` and `NSArray`

```
 List<object> list = new List<object>();
 list.Add(new NSString());    //set
 NSString str = list[0] as NSString;   //get
```

Comment: BTW,we can also use `NSArray` ,`NSMutableArray` ,`NSMutableDictionary `,`NSDictionary` directly in `Xamarin.ios`.

Comment: xia Thank you so much for your explanation.

Comment: Actually I want I want to convert logic in xamarin.ios for xamarin.Android

Comment: You can use Dictionary and List both on xamarin.ios and xamarin.Android.

Comment: why can't we use Hash Map instead of Dictionary?

Comment: You also can use Hashtable , but i think Dictionary is more friendly to use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273139/c-sharp-java-hashmap-equivalent